# Validating Matching Strings

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

When I use the Validation feature in Laravel, how can I add a pre-defined strings that are allowed in an Input?

For example, let's say I want the Input to contain only one of the following: `foo,bar,baz`, how can I do that?

```
$validator = Validator::make($credentials, [
      'profile' => 'required|max:255', // Here I want Predefined allowed values for it
]);
```

Comment: Have you tried regex matching on the field for the words that you want to match ?

Comment: Right now I am using the php `in_array` to manually check and throw excemption and havent tried the laravel validation regex. can you show a sample on that please?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is recommended in Laravel docs to put the validation rules in an array when they get bigger and I thought 3 rules were sufficient. I think it makes it for a more readable content but you do not have to. I added the `regex` portion below and I have it works. I am not that great with regexing stuff. Let me know.

```
$validator = Validator::make($credentials, [
      'profile' => ["required" , "max:255", "regex:(foo|bar|baz)"]  
]);
```

Comment: Perfect! That worked! When the input doesnt match the regex, it throws the exception `The profile format is invalid`. I also removed the `"max:255"` since I am matching it with the regex anyways. Thank you so much @ODelibalta This is exactly what I wanted! :)

Answer (score 46):

Best to use the 'in' validation rule like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($credentials, [
      'profile' => ["required" , "max:255", "in:foo,bar,baz"]  
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me in Laravel 9:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
 
Validator::make($data, [
    'toppings' => [
        'required',
        Rule::notIn(['sprinkles', 'cherries']),
    ],
]);
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-not-in

For the opposite you could use `Rule::in(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])`