# Accept just Gmail and Ymail in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a function and say in register form, user can put just Gmail or Ymail

And if the email isn't from them, shows: "Please put a valid email"

Register controller:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'username' => 'required|string|alpha_dash|max:25|unique:users',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating Matching Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439203/validating-matching-strings)

Answer (score 2):

To put some customized message, you need to paste third arguments to Validator::make

[See this documentation link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-error-messages)

And in the email validation rules, you need to add regex rule
like this

```
regex:/gmail|ymail]/
```

[Regex Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-regex)

```
$message = ['email.regex' => 'Please put a valid email'];

return Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users|regex:/gmail|ymail]/',
    'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    'username' => 'required|string|alpha_dash|max:25|unique:users',
], $message);
```

Comment: My problem isn't for the massage, I don't know how can I check the email puted was a google mail or yahoo mail?

Comment: seed the regex in the validator
regex:/gmail|yahool]/

All word beetwen / and / separate by | is check

Comment: How can I find the services name? for example, if I want add outlook to the emails, what I write here? (regex)

Comment: /gmail|yahoo|outlook/

Comment: @Amirhossein Don’t broaden the subject inside a comment. Specify everything in you question.